# Incorrect syntax near IF statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, if-statement

I am using an IF statement in order to choose a column that isn't NULL in an SQL SELECT procedure. However, I get an error saying there is something wrong with my syntax near keyword IF.

```
DECLARE @imgURL_prefix VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @imgSmall_Suffix VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @imgLarge_Suffix VARCHAR(100)

SET @imgURL_prefix = '//sohimages.com/images/images_soh/'
SET @imgSmall_Suffix = '-1.jpg'
SET @imgLarge_Suffix = '-2.jpg'

SELECT
    P.ProductCode as ProductCode,
    P.HideProduct as HideProduct,
    P.Photos_Cloned_From as Photos_Cloned_From,
    @imgURL_prefix +
        LOWER( IF P.Photos_Cloned_From IS NOT NULL
            P.Photos_Cloned_From
        ELSE
            P.ProductCode
        END )
        + @imgSmall_Suffix as PhotoURL_Small,
    @imgURL_prefix +
        LOWER( IF P.Photos_Cloned_From IS NOT NULL
            P.Photos_Cloned_From
        ELSE
            P.ProductCode
        END )
        + @imgLarge_Suffix as PhotoURL_Large,
    P.PhotoURL_Small as OriginalSmall,
    P.PhotoURL_Large as OriginalLarge
FROM
    Products_Joined P
```

The script works fine without the IF statement, using just `LOWER(P.ProductCode)` in it's place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `IIF(Expression, true, false)` in sql server 2012 and later editions and for older editions you have CASE statement

```
/*********  SQL SERVER 2012+ ***********/

SELECT
    P.ProductCode as ProductCode,
    P.HideProduct as HideProduct,
    P.Photos_Cloned_From as Photos_Cloned_From,
    @imgURL_prefix +
        LOWER( IIF( P.Photos_Cloned_From IS NOT NULL , P.Photos_Cloned_From, P.ProductCode))
        + @imgSmall_Suffix as PhotoURL_Small,
    @imgURL_prefix +
        LOWER( IIF (P.Photos_Cloned_From IS NOT NULL, P.Photos_Cloned_From, P.ProductCode))
        + @imgLarge_Suffix as PhotoURL_Large,
    P.PhotoURL_Small as OriginalSmall,
    P.PhotoURL_Large as OriginalLarge
FROM
    Products_Joined P

/*********  SQL SERVER Older Versions ***********/

SELECT
    P.ProductCode as ProductCode,
    P.HideProduct as HideProduct,
    P.Photos_Cloned_From as Photos_Cloned_From,
    @imgURL_prefix +
        LOWER( CASE WHEN P.Photos_Cloned_From IS NOT NULL 
              THEN P.Photos_Cloned_From ELSE P.ProductCode END)
        + @imgSmall_Suffix as PhotoURL_Small,
    @imgURL_prefix +
        LOWER( CASE WHEN P.Photos_Cloned_From IS NOT NULL 
               THEN P.Photos_Cloned_From ELSE P.ProductCode END)
        + @imgLarge_Suffix as PhotoURL_Large,
    P.PhotoURL_Small as OriginalSmall,
    P.PhotoURL_Large as OriginalLarge
FROM
    Products_Joined P
```

Comment: Is it possible to make the entire expression for PhotoURL_Small and PhotoURL_Large a variable like `@imgur_url_large`? I want to make a `WHERE` clause stating not to export files that have that same field already filled out.